# Specifying vocabulary input in LDA

Tags: python, nlp, cluster-analysis, gensim, lda

I am trying to understand how to use LDA in my case. I have a corpus of many documents and I want to see how a very specific set of words and ngrams are distributed across topics. Is there a way to specify a list of specific words as a vocabulary for topic modeling?

I have been working with the gensim implementation and I believe the argument `id2word` handles this, but the documentation is not clear to me. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: do you want only specific list of keyword to be used in your topic modelling ???

Comment: yes, that is what i want.

Answer (score 0):

LDA’s approach to topic modelling is it considers each document as a collection of topics in a certain proportion. And each topic as a collection of keywords, again, in a certain proportion.

Once you provide the algorithm with the number of topics, all it does it to rearrange the topics distribution within the documents and keywords distribution within the topics to obtain a good composition of topic-keywords distribution.

The two main inputs to the `LDA` topic model are the dictionary or vocabulary(`id2word`) and the corpus.

You can use something like this to achieve this:

```
import gensim.corpora as corpora

# Create Dictionary/Vocabulary
id2word = corpora.Dictionary(data_lemmatized)

# Create Corpus
texts = data_lemmatized

# Term Document Frequency
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Scikit learn Countvectorizer for this

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from gensim import matutils
from gensim.models.ldamodel import LdaModel

text = ['computer time graph', 'survey response eps', 'human system computer','machinelearning is very hot topic','python win the race for simplicity as compared to other programming language']

# suppose this are the word that you want to be used in your vocab 
vocabulary = ['machine','python','learning','human', 'system','hot','time']

vect = CountVectorizer(vocabulary = vocabulary)
x = vect.fit_transform(text)

feature_name = vect.get_feature_names()

# now you can use matutils helper function of gensim
model = LdaModel(matutils.Sparse2Corpus(x),num_topic=3,id2word=dict([(i, s) for i, s in enumerate(feature_name)]))

#printing the topic 
model.show_topics()
```

[image]

```
 #to see the vocab that use being used 
 print(vect.get_feature_names())
  ['machine', 'python', 'learning', 'human', 'system', 'hot', 'time'] # you will get the feature that you want include
```